# Snake Identification in India

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology, snake

**Location: Kharagpur, West Bengal, India.**
**Time: Near the end of September at around 1:00 pm.**
This snake was spotted in a drain near my hostel in Kharagpur, West Bengal, India. Can somebody help me identify this species or at least tell me if it is venomous or not? It is hard for me as I can not distinguish its head from the piece of "trash" in the drain.

After a bit of research, I now believe that this is "Striped Keelback". However, I would like someone to confirm this.

[image: The Snake. I believe some kind if "trash" in the drain is reducing the clarity of the shape of its head.]

Comment: The trash might just be its lunch, a rodent perhaps.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Yes, I was thinking the same thing.